# Excel: which values to increment and which to not in autofill

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to make a word encoder that has a column in which you input letters and a column that will be referenced to in the function that detects the letter and encodes it. This is my function:

```
=IF(A1 = "A", D1, IF(A1 = "B", D2, IF(A1 = "C", D3, IF(A1 = "D", D4, IF(A1 = "E", D5, IF(A1 = "F", D6, IF(A1 = "G", D7, IF(A1 = "H", D8, IF(A1 = "I", D9, IF(A1 = "J", D10, IF(A1 = "K", D11, IF(A1 = "L", D12, IF(A1 = "M", D13, IF(A1 = "N", D14, IF(A1 = "O", D15, IF(A1 = "P", D16, IF(A1 = "Q", D17, IF(A1 = "R", D18, IF(A1 = "S", D19, IF(A1 = "T", D20, IF(A1 = "U", D21, IF(A1 = "V", D22, IF(A1 = "W", D23, IF(A1 = "X", D24, IF(A1 = "Y", D25, IF(A1 = "Z", D26, "0"))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Column D is what I would use as a reference. I need it to auto-fill down the third column (the encoded column)  26 times but only incrementing the A1 to an A2 then to a A3 down the column without incrementing the D1, D2, and D3 to D2, D3, and D4 as I auto-fill the column.

Is there a way to lock the D values so that only the A values increase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I suggest a slightly shorter formula than 26 nested IFs:

```
=INDEX($D$1:$D$26,FIND(A1,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))
```

Copy down.

The reference to $D$1:$D$26 uses $ signs, so it will not change when copied down. The reference to A1 is relative and will change to A2, A3, etc when copied down.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly you need to use `$` in cell references to specify portions of cell references that would be absolute vs relative.

For example:

Copying the formula `=A1+1` down (or across) accordingly.

However if we always wanted to use A1 then you would use `= $A$1 +1`

The `$` can be used in either or both positions depending on what you need. You might only want `=$A1` or `=A$1` depending on what you are doing, and which direction (down or across) you are coping.

You can find more information [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-538396b3-990e-4b44-9d9c-28b4151d7d21).

Answer (score 1):

If you put a dollar before a letter or a number it will lock it so it won't change when it autofills, so that would give you:

`=IF(A1 = "A", $D$1, IF(A1 = "B", $D$2, IF(A1 = "C", $D$3, IF(A1 = "$D$", $D$4, IF(A1 = "E", $D$5, IF(A1 = "F", $D$6, IF(A1 = "G", $D$7, IF(A1 = "H", $D$8, IF(A1 = "I", $D$9, IF(A1 = "J", $D$10, IF(A1 = "K", $D$11, IF(A1 = "L", $D$12, IF(A1 = "M", $D$13, IF(A1 = "N", $D$14, IF(A1 = "O", $D$15, IF(A1 = "P", $D$16, IF(A1 = "Q", $D$17, IF(A1 = "R", $D$18, IF(A1 = "S", $D$19, IF(A1 = "T", $D$20, IF(A1 = "U", $D$21, IF(A1 = "V", $D$22, IF(A1 = "W", $D$23, IF(A1 = "X", $D$24, IF(A1 = "Y", $D$25, IF(A1 = "Z", $D$26, "0"))))))))))))))))))))))))))`

However, it looks like you've used nested if statements to do what's already a built-in funcionality to excel.  If you put a table like the following in, you could just use `=vlookup(A1,$E$1:$F$26,2,FALSE)` and get the same result.

```
|COL E|COL F|
| A   |your |
| B   |     |
| C   |subs-|
| D   |titu-|
| E   |tions|
| F   |     |
| G   | go  |
| H   |     |
| I   |here |
| J   |     |
| K   |     |
| L   |     |
| M   |     |
| N   |     |
| O   |     |
| P   |     |
| Q   |     |
| R   |     |
| S   |     |
| T   |     |
| U   |     |
| V   |     |
| W   |     |
| X   |     |
| Y   |     |
| Z   |     |
```

Also, use F4 when typing a reference to toggle through absolute reference options without having to type a dollar (A1, $A1, A$1, and $A$1)

Comment: Thank you, I dont know why you'd answer on a 10 month old question, but I appreciate the answer.

Comment: ... I don't know why I have a 10 month old question open... my mistake.  Thanks for your thank you anyway haha

Comment: @teylyn I am no longer working on that project and your "one liner" worked well. I am thanking Some_Guy for the effort (albeit late) to answer my question. Now I don't know if it was supposed to sound so, but your comment came off as a but rude.